# How to get SendGrid response status as a string?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sendgrid

I am having a problem retrieving an HTTP response code from SendGrid, and then updating a label based on that response.  Since the SendGrid call uses an async method I am not able to get return a response.statuscode;

this is my code:

```
 protected void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                lblmsg.InnerText = SendMail(txtEmailId.Text.ToString(), 
                txtMessage.Text.ToString());  //------------

        }




        private String SendMail(String EmailId, String Message)
        {
            var status="";
           Execute(EmailId, Message).Wait();
                  return status;  
        }



   async Task Execute(String EmailId, String Message)
        {
            var apiKey = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Sender");
            var subject = "Testing Email";
            var to = new EmailAddress(EmailId, "Reciever");
            var plainTextContent = "You have recieved this message from me";
            var htmlContent = Message + "<br><i>-Message sent by me</i>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var status = response.StatusCode;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a value from an async method it must be awaited.  See the example method call below:

```
private async Task<System.Net.HttpStatusCode> Execute(String EmailId, String Message)
        {
            var apiKey = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Sender");
            var subject = "Testing Email";
            var to = new EmailAddress(EmailId, "Reciever");
            var plainTextContent = "You have recieved this message from me";
            var htmlContent = Message + "<br><i>-Message sent by me</i>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return response.StatusCode;

        }

private async Task GetStatusCodeExample(String EmailId, String Message)
{
    var statusCode = await Execute(EmailId, Message);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

update your code to use the following along with the above updated Execute method:

```
protected void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lblmsg.InnerText = SendMail(txtEmailId.Text.ToString(), 
     txtMessage.Text.ToString());  //------------


private String SendMail(String EmailId, String Message)
{
     var task = Execute(EmailId, Message);
     task.Wait();
     return ((int)task.Result).ToString();  
}
```

Comment: how can i get status code from even ```private async Task GetStatusCodeExample(...``` method?

Comment: you won't need to!  just use Execute.  The `private async Task GetStatusCodeExample` is just example syntax of how to do what you need.

Comment: please share your label assignment code for further assistance.

Comment: @stack_user added code to my answer based on your latest edit.

Comment: it worked with task.status rather than task.result ,THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Your method does not allow a return value, since you declared it as `async Task`. That means it's an `async` method that returns nothing (it just a returns a `Task` so the caller knows when it's done, but no actual value).

If you want to return something from an `async` method, you need to use a `Task<T>` return type, where `T` is the type of value you want to return.

So in this case, it should be:

```
async Task<HttpStatusCode> Execute(String EmailId, String Message)
```

Then you can `return response.StatusCode`

Here's some additional reading that might help you understand `async` code better:

- [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)
- [The Task asynchronous programming model in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index)
- [Async in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth)

Comment: but how to store it in variable?

Comment: The same way you already did: `var status = await Execute(emailId, message);`